# In PHP, echo a div with the id of a variable

Tags: php, html

i want to echo a div in PHP, and set the ID equal to the value of $divName, but i cannot get it to work

Here is my code:

```
$divName = "divText"
echo '<div id=$divName></div>'
```

Comment: Variables are not interpolated in single quotes.  Basic php.

Comment: you should study more the basics about PHP like how to echo: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php Follow some tutorials for starters first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Just do it like this:

```
$divName = "divText";
echo '<div id="'.$divName.'"></div>';
```

You should read the PHP Documentation. This is really basic stuff.
http://php.net/docs.php

Comment: If I wanted some prefix to that div id, would then be echo '<div id="somestring'.$divName.'"></div>'; ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add semicolons (**;**) at the end of each command line?

Change single quotes (**'**) to double quotes (**"**) and that it:

```
$divName = "divText";
echo "<div id=$divName></div>";
```